# How does a linked list know when its element has been removed from the list and adjust?

Tags: c++

I made a singly linked list and am creating an iterator for it but I am running into a problem when the element currently pointed to gets removed from the list. I have a class called list and within it, I have a nested class called iter. Currently iter's only field is a *currentNode pointer (it gets passed in a node in the constructor).

So how do I handle when the element that it is pointing to gets deleted. My first thought was that I should try to handle that in my list's remove() functions but I don't think it is possible to / don't know how to tell from the list's point of view whether the current element is being pointed to by the iterator (the iterator's currentNode pointer seems to not be in the scope of the class based on the compiler's errors). My second thought was to try to handle it from the iterator itself, but I can't figure out how to even begin to go about that.

I'm sorry if the answer is really simple. I couldn't find the answer anywhere online which makes me think that it might be but I just can't figure out how to handle this for the life of me. Thank you!

Comment: Is iter pointing only to the current element, or iter may point to other elements in the list?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `std::list` instead?

Comment: You mention a "compiler error", what is the actual error?  Please show your actual code.

Comment: How does a list know when its element has been removed? How does an int know when it's been incremented? Who says anyone has to know any of those things?

Comment: Fabio, I don't exactly understand your quesiton. It may point to any element on the list (i.e. it has the ++ operators overloaded so that it can access any other element), but the case that I am interested in helping to solve is when the object pointed to is the one that is removed from the list.

Comment: Do you need to handle this? Isn't it the programmer's job not to use iterators to elements that they deleted? What the Standard Library does is provide functions like `erase()` that return a new valid iterator to the next element when one is deleted.

Comment: It all depends on what behavior you want to achieve. For example, in `std::list` the iterator simply becomes invalid which means you get undefined behaviour if you try to dereference it.

Comment: @Code: well, if you pass the iterator to your `remove()` function, technically `remove()` could update the iterator to point at a different node after removing the current node. But that kind of goes against how most iterators operate.

Comment: And this is to help me practice for my data structures course where I am expected to be able to create an iterator like this. And there is normally no compiler error. The only error comes when I try to edit the "currentNode" pointer of the iterator from the list class which, as expected, just says that currentNode has not been delcared.

Comment: @Code: Then you are not using it correctly. Again, please show your actual code, stop making us guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh I never thought of creating a new iterator that points to the next element. That's exactly the kind of solution I was hoping to find on here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list does not need to know anything about the iterator or its content.  When the iterator removes its current node from the list, the iterator is invalidated.  Even iterators in most standard STL container behave that same way.  If you look at `std::list`, for instance, its `erase(iterator)` method returns a *new* iterator that represents the *next* node in the list following the node that was removed.  You can do the same in your own `remove()` method.  Otherwise, `remove()` would have to update the iterator to point at a different node, but that tends to go against how iterators typically operate.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to find. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options.

1. If you dereference an iterator to an object that doesn't exist it is undefined behavior. The standard library does it and it is accepted. Also it is easy to implement since you don't need to handle that case.
2. Keep a `std::shared_ptr` to the element. That way the value does not get deleted as long as the iterator exists. You have to pay a performance penalty for doing this even if you do not use the feature. Additionally it can be perceived as hiding a bug.